# Where should my cross-platform FireMonkey app store its settings?

Tags: delphi, cross-platform, settings, firemonkey, ini

What are the best practices for where a cross-platform FireMonkey program should put *INI* files? Are *INI* files even the right approach?

Comment: I'm wondering if this is my solution: System.IOUtils.TPath is has system-specific paths baked in and switches based on platform. I need to match the paths it chooses against the answers I'm getting here to see if this is useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Android: in "shared storage"

For MacOS: in INI file

https://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2015/06/11/ccr-prefsinifile-on-github/

CCR.PrefsIniFile on GitHub by Chris Rolliston (he is on stackoverflow also: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2778930/chris-rolliston)

> Just a small post to say the the native Preferences API wrappers for Android, iOS and OS X I published to Google Code a while back are now on GitHib:
>
> https://github.com/chrisrolliston/CCR.PrefsIniFile
>
> Both the Android and Apple versions should also now compile in XE8.

Comment: Chris' solution does more than just resolve "my where to store" question. This looks like my best option.

Comment: there's no license though provided: https://github.com/chrisrolliston/CCR.PrefsIniFile/issues/2

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching for one location that will fit all platforms then I'm afraid you won't find it.

You see each platforms has its own preference on where the settings files are stored.

So you should read each platforms guidelines and make sure your program uses those locations.

Failing to do so and trying to save the settings in some different folder might fail completely as many platforms limit of which folders can your application access at all.

---

Now as for which format should you use? Should this be INI files or something else?

On windows it is completely up to you which format you use. You can use system registry, INI files (pretty common), XML files (becoming quite common lately) or even some custom formats like Typed files (binary files) that Delphi is capable of working with.

But this does not apply to all platforms. Some platforms might even limit you in which format you store your settings.

So again you should read the platform preferences on this matter and adapt.

Answer (score 0):

In windows INI files became ubiquitous as a fast, easy to use method. But as they became larger they became much slower and it was difficult to implement structured storage. Hence the move away from INI files towards Registry/Registries. But that is not an option for cross platform, so there has been some drive back towards INI file structures, but depending on size this could still be slow. One of the more interesting approaches I have seen is in this skill sprint which (mis)uses JSON to create files equivalent to old INI files (and allows structure too). See here [JSON - the new INI file](http://edn.embarcadero.com/jp/article/44008). As to where, I think you need to read the recommendations for each target as the recommended location could be different for each.

Comment: I do a lot with JSON. I plan on using name/value pairs in this case because I'm reading/writing via TStringLists and I've gotten used to keeping everything name/value for simplicity.